# Call re-sizing function after lazy loading of image

Tags: jquery, image, crop, resize-crop

I am trying to call re-sizing function after lazy loading of image. I have simple jquery plugin given below that can resize and crop the image to correct size by tweaking the image url.

**Crop JS:**

```
$.extend($.lazyLoadXT, {
    onload:myfunc
});

function myfunc(){
    var w = 200;
var h = 150;
$('.crop').find('img').each(function(n, image){
  var image = $(image);
  image.attr({src : image.attr('src').replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/,'s' + w + '-h' + h +'-c')});
  image.attr('width',w);
  image.attr('height',h);
 });
}
```

*HTLM:*

```
<div class="crop">
<img data-src="images/uxzfpd-t500x500.jpg"/>
</div>
```

`onload` handler called when element is successfully loaded by [LazyloadXT](https://github.com/ressio/lazy-load-xt) plugin. But it unable call my jquery Image Crop plugin. *See Fiddle:*http://jsfiddle.net/e0myc0po/12/

My question it why it’s not working or Image Crop plugin is not working?
Image should crop to 200X150 Px, but it's still 500x500 Px (original size).

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `image.css('width',w);`

Comment: no, any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `$.extend` block to the end after lazyLoadXT:

```
function myfunc() {
     var w = 200;
     var h = 150;
     $('.crop').find('img').each(function(n, image) {
          var image = $(image);
          image.attr({
                src: image.attr('src').replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/, 's' + w + '-h' + h + '-c')
          });
          image.attr('width', w);
          image.attr('height', h);
     });
}

/* LazyLoadXT */

! function(a, b, c, d) {
     function e(a, b) {
          return a[b] === d ? t[b] : a[b]
     }

     function f() {
          var a = b.pageYOffset;
          return a === d ? r.scrollTop : a
     }

     function g(a, b) {
          var c = t["on" + a];
          c && (w(c) ? c.call(b[0]) : (c.addClass && b.addClass(c.addClass), c.removeClass && b.removeClass(c.removeClass))),
                b.trigger("lazy" + a, [b]), k()
     }

     function h(b) {
          g(b.type, a(this)
                .off(p, h))
     }

     function i(c) {
          if (A.length) {
                c = c || t.forceLoad, B = 1 / 0;
                var d, e, i = f(),
                     j = b.innerHeight || r.clientHeight,
                     k = b.innerWidth || r.clientWidth;
                for (d = 0, e = A.length; e > d; d++) {
                     var l, m = A[d],
                          o = m[0],
                          q = m[n],
                          s = !1,
                          u = c;
                     if (z(r, o)) {
                          if (c || !q.visibleOnly || o.offsetWidth || o.offsetHeight) {
                                if (!u) {
                                     var v = o.getBoundingClientRect(),
                                          x = q.edgeX,
                                          y = q.edgeY;
                                     l = v.top + i - y - j, u = i >= l && v.bottom > -y && v.left <= k + x && v.right > -x
                                }
                                if (u) {
                                     g("show", m);
                                     var C = q.srcAttr,
                                          D = w(C) ? C(m) : o.getAttribute(C);
                                     D && (m.on(p, h), o.src = D), s = !0
                                } else B > l && (B = l)
                          }
                     } else s = !0;
                     s && (A.splice(d--, 1), e--)
                }
                e || g("complete", a(r))
          }
     }

     function j() {
          C > 1 ? (C = 1, i(), setTimeout(j, t.throttle)) : C = 0
     }

     function k(a) {
          A.length && (a && "scroll" === a.type && a.currentTarget === b && B >= f() || (C || setTimeout(j, 0), C = 2))
     }

     function l() {
          v.lazyLoadXT()
     }

     function m() {
          i(!0)
     }
     var n = "lazyLoadXT",
          o = "lazied",
          p = "load error",
          q = "lazy-hidden",
          r = c.documentElement || c.body,
          s = b.onscroll === d || !!b.operamini || !r.getBoundingClientRect,
          t = {
                autoInit: !0,
                selector: "img[data-src]",
                blankImage: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXYzh8+PB/AAffA0nNPuCLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC",
                throttle: 99,
                forceLoad: s,
                loadEvent: "pageshow",
                updateEvent: "load orientationchange resize scroll touchmove focus",
                forceEvent: "",
                oninit: {
                     removeClass: "lazy"
                },
                onshow: {
                     addClass: q
                },
                onload: {
                     removeClass: q,
                     addClass: "lazy-loaded",
                },
                onerror: {
                     removeClass: q
                },
                checkDuplicates: !0
          },
          u = {
                srcAttr: "data-src",
                edgeX: 0,
                edgeY: 0,
                visibleOnly: !0
          },
          v = a(b),
          w = a.isFunction,
          x = a.extend,
          y = a.data || function(b, c) {
                return a(b)
                     .data(c)
          },
          z = a.contains || function(a, b) {
                for (; b = b.parentNode;)
                     if (b === a) return !0;
                return !1
          },
          A = [],
          B = 0,
          C = 0;
     a[n] = x(t, u, a[n]), a.fn[n] = function(c) {
                c = c || {};
                var d, f = e(c, "blankImage"),
                     h = e(c, "checkDuplicates"),
                     i = e(c, "scrollContainer"),
                     j = {};
                a(i)
                     .on("scroll", k);
                for (d in u) j[d] = e(c, d);
                return this.each(function(d, e) {
                     if (e === b) a(t.selector)
                          .lazyLoadXT(c);
                     else {
                          if (h && y(e, o)) return;
                          var i = a(e)
                                .data(o, 1);
                          f && "IMG" === e.tagName && !e.src && (e.src = f), i[n] = x({}, j), g("init", i), A.push(i)
                     }
                })
          }, a(c)
          .ready(function() {

                g("start", v), v.on(t.loadEvent, l)
                     .on(t.updateEvent, k)
                     .on(t.forceEvent, m), a(c)
                     .on(t.updateEvent, k), t.autoInit && l()
          })
}(window.jQuery || window.Zepto || window.$, window, document),
function(a) {

     var b = a.lazyLoadXT;
     b.selector += ",video,iframe[data-src]", b.videoPoster = "data-poster", a(document)
          .on("lazyshow", "video", function(c, d) {

                var e = d.lazyLoadXT.srcAttr,
                     f = a.isFunction(e);
                d.attr("poster", d.attr(b.videoPoster))
                     .children("source,track")
                     .each(function(b, c) {
                          var d = a(c);
                          d.attr("src", f ? e(d) : d.attr(e));
                     }), this.load()
          })
}(window.jQuery || window.Zepto || window.$);

$.extend($.lazyLoadXT, {
     onload: myfunc
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e0myc0po/16/

Comment: You should add your code here as well and not only link to jsfiddle!

Comment: Was just formatting it.. be patient.  Why the downvote?  This works

Comment: To me the important info here is the placement of the code, and the fact that one needs to come after the other.  I created a jfiddle which illustrates this and shows it working.  I can't believe you would downvote a correct answer which provides the important information because it doesn't spoon feed you the code.

Comment: I didn't down vote because of that, but because you provided a fiddle without code, you shoudn't since jsfiddle.net could go down, then your demo will be lost forever!

Comment: I understand, but the fact remains that my answer without *any* code at all would have been sufficient for him to understand why things weren't working.  Even the jfiddle was unnecessary.  For me, the important thing is to offer the concept that will help someone understand how to correct the problem.  Not to write code for them.

Comment: Do you want to provide a link?  Maybe you have the old js cached in your browser?

Comment: I put crop JS like that: `$(document).ready(function() { $.extend($.lazyLoadXT, { onload:slycolors }); function slycolors(){ var w = 100; var h = 70; $('.sly-scroll').find('img').each(function(n, image){ var image = $(image); image.attr({src : image.attr('src').replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/,'s' + w + '-h' + h +'-c')}); image.attr('width',w); image.attr('height',h); }); } }); After LazyLoadXT Script.`

Comment: Sorry I can't understand from your comment.. the fiddle I set up works and was based on revisions to the fiddle you posted.  If you are still unable to get yours working based on that maybe you can create another fiddle illustrating what you actually have on your site.  You may be looking at a completely unrelated problem but at any rate you need to offer a demonstration of things in a non working state or I can't be of much help.